# How to use Tensorflow Dataset with OpenCV preprocessing?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am creating a pipeline for text recognition and I want to use Tensorflow Dtatasets to load the data through some preprocessing with OpenCV

I was following this tutorial 
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#applying_arbitrary_python_logic_with_tfpy_func
and I have this preprocessing function:

```
def preprocess(path, imgSize=(1024, 64), dataAugmentation=False):

    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    th, img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + 
    cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    # create target image and copy sample image into it
    (wt, ht) = imgSize
    (h, w) = img.shape
    fx = w / wt
    fy = h / ht
    f = max(fx, fy)
    newSize = (max(min(wt, int(w / f)), 1),
               max(min(ht, int(h / f)), 1))  # scale according to f (result at 
    least 1 and at most wt or ht)
    img = cv2.resize(img, newSize)

    # add random padding to fit the target size if data augmentation is true
    # otherwise add padding to the right
    if newSize[1] == ht:
        if dataAugmentation:
            padding_width_left = np.random.random_integers(0, wt-newSize[0])
            img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, 0, 0, padding_width_left, wt-newSize[0]-padding_width_left, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, (0, 0))
        else:
            img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, 0, 0, 0, wt - newSize[0], cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, (0, 0))
    else:
        img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, int(np.floor((ht - newSize[1])/2)), int(np.ceil((ht - newSize[1])/2)), 0, 0, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, None, (0, 0))

    # transpose for TF
    img = cv2.transpose(img)

    return img
```

But if I use this

```
list_images = os.listdir(images_path)
image_paths = []
for i in range(len(list_images)):
    image_paths.append("iam-database/images/" + list_images[i])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_paths)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda filename: tuple(tf.py_function(preprocess, [filename], [tf.uint8])))
print(dataset)
```

I get shape unknown and it seems that the preprocessing function is not parsed. What should I do?

Comment: Where do you iterate through your data?

Comment: What is the error you get ? This line `dataset = dataset.map(lambda filename: tuple(tf.py_func(preprocess, [filename], [tf.uint8])))
` doesn't shown me any error. I execute your code but don't see the error. Do you mean this `<MapDataset shapes: (<unknown>,), types: (tf.uint8,)>` ?

Comment: @borarak In the bottom script. Don't I need an array with the paths in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan I don't get any error. But If I print the dataset I get unknown shape and the preprocess function is not parsed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run this preprocess function inside dataset API pipeline, you need to wrap it with `tf.py_function` It's the successor for deprecated `py_func`. Main difference is it can be palced on GPU and can work with eager tensors. You can read more in docs.

```py
def preprocess(path, imgSize = (1024, 64), dataAugmentation = False):
    path = path.numpy().decode("utf-8") # .numpy() retrieves data from eager tensor
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    ...
    return img
```

At this point img is a . The rest of the function is up to you

This parse function is a wrapper for dataset pipeline. It receives filename as tensor with bytestring inside.

```py
def parse_func(filename):
    out = tf.py_function(preprocess, [filename], tf.uint8)
    return out


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(path)
dataset = dataset.map(pf).batch(1)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(iterator.get_next()))
```

Comment: If I do not run `tf.enable_eager_execution()` then I cannot do `.numpy()` and it means I cannot do preprocessing using OpenCV right?

Comment: You still can use opencv, but if you're using TF1.x you need py_func

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong in your code (or missing based on the code sample you provided). First, you need to iterate your data to actually call the parse function. In eager mode you could do something like:

```
for x in dataset:
    print(x)
```

Secondly you cannot directly call your opencv `imread` on your path since it's a `tf.Tensor` at that stage. Look at the [map](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) docs, it takes a Dataset as input and returns another Dataset. So at the very least you need something like `str(path.numpy())` to convert it back to a string that you can feed to `imread`. A better suggestion is to use the tensorflow inbuilt function to read your file, decode an image and then convert it to numpy. Check out `tf.io.decode_jpeg`

NOTE: i have used `tensorflow 2-0-alpha` to give you the examples, so based on your tf version the API will change slightly but the idea is the same

Comment: `tf.io.decode_jpeg`  returns tensor, and can't be directly used with opencv

Comment: yes, i think i made it clear "A better suggestion is to use the tensorflow inbuilt function to read your file, decode an image and then convert it to numpy. Check out tf.io.decode_jpeg" , so he still has to convert it to numpy before feeding it to opencv

Comment: Problem is to convert you'll have to evaluate tensor. But you're right that it's always better to stick native TF preprocessing, except use of other libraries is absolutely necessary