# py_function mapping return unknown shape of batched tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to write a preprocessing function using OpenCV through tensorflow dataset pipeline. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606909/how-to-use-tensorflow-dataset-with-opencv-preprocessing) do not work in my case.

To explicit my point, consider this dummy tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
ds1 = tf.random.uniform(
    (6,5,4,3),
    minval=0,
    maxval=None,
    dtype=tf.dtypes.float64,
    seed=None,
    name=None
)
ds2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ds1).batch(batch_size=2)
ds2
Out[4]: <BatchDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5, 4, 3), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)>
```

Next, my goal is to apply preprocessing step on these "array" (a.k.a images obtained using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` in practices...)

Some dummy functions :

```
def preprocess_images(x):
    return x+1

def parse_func_decorator(x):
    return tf.py_function(preprocess_images, [x], tf.float64)
```

Now begins the mystery that I want to understand: Applying the preprocessing function via py_function gives unknown shape :

```
ds3 = ds2.map(parse_func_decorator)
ds3
Out[7]: <MapDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=<unknown>, dtype=tf.float64, name=None)>
```

On the other hand, mapping the preprocessing function, directly, conserve dimension

```
ds5 = ds2.map(preprocess_images)
ds5
Out[9]: <MapDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5, 4, 3), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: When you call `py_function`, why do you use brackets in the x `[x]`?

Comment: syntax reason !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found that mapping a keras Input layers solves this issues.

```
data_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5, 4, 3))
])

ds4 = ds2.map(lambda x: (data_rescale(x)))
ds4
Out[19]: <MapDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5, 4, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)>
```

Comment: can you share your solution please? I think I'm running in a very similar issue but I'm already using input layers

Comment: Hi, I have added my solution. Hope doesn't come late ! HNY !