Saving tensorflow dataset extremely slow after applying filter
Relatively new to tensorflow here, and I am facing an issue where I have not yet managed to find a good answer through searching. So here goes:
I am trying to understand why applying a filter function to my tensorflow dataset, suddenly makes the time it takes to write the dataset to disk, seemingly explode. The time jumps from around 1 min to nearly two hours.
My code is Python 3.8, Tensorflow 2.11.1.
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage import filters  

#Filtering function
def meijering_filter(x):
    filtered = filters.meijering(x)
    return filtered

#Import training data
training_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        "path_to_training_dataset",
        labels=None,
        batch_size=5,
        image_size=(480, 640),
        shuffle=True,
        seed=42,
        subset='training',
        validation_split=0.2,
        color_mode='grayscale'
    )

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
normalized_train_dataset = training_dataset.map(lambda x: (normalization_layer(x)))
feat_training_dataset = normalized_train_dataset.map(lambda x: tf.numpy_function(meijering_filter, [x], tf.float32))

#Reshaping data, since the numpy_function() returns tensors with an unknown shape
data_reshape = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(480, 640, 1))])
feat_training_dataset = feat_training_dataset.map(lambda x: (data_reshape(x)))

#Saving tensorflow dataset for later consumption
feat_training_dataset.save("save_path_on_disk")

I am aware that the save() requires at least one compute of the dataset, and that the meijering filter is somewhat compute intensive. Still, timing this based on a take(1) on my dataset, I expect that computation to take a few minutes (the take(1) I timed to 0.12s, and my entire dataset is only around 1500 images).
I also tried not applying the data_reshape(), but that did not make a notable difference.
Can someone help me understand why the execution of the save() takes nearly two hours in the code above, and is there a way to remedy this?

Have you tried to set num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE to your map functions?
And just a note, you should probably use tf.ensure_shape to set the shape of your tensor.

Good suggestion! Setting the num_parallel_calls in the map functions cut the execution time from around 2h to a bit under 30min. Still a bit on the long side, but a substantial improvement, so I guess not taking advantage of parallelization was one issue.
To your second point, I tried using ensure_shape, but couldn't get it to work, so I basically followed the solution proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73260467/py-function-mapping-return-unknown-shape-of-batched-tensorflow-dataset

For the rest, it's hard to know. You could look at the profiler to help you get some better measurements. take(1) is not necessarily the best baseline to use.
